# How to configure Maven in Jaspersoft Studio?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I'm building a complex project that depends of various modules. For exporting to PDF I'm using *JasperReport API* and for developing reports I'm using Jaspersoft Studio, version 6.4.0.

In the way to avoid duplicated queries, I'm sending all data via parameters to the report, the type of this parameters are custom beans. Those beans are contained in another project (This must be so, because those beans are being used in view layer of another application). When I import those beans as jar library dependency contained in a ".jar" file directly in *Jaspersoft Studio* project, reports compile perfectly.

Now I'm trying to use Maven to include this dependencies, but *Jaspersoft Studio* doesn't contain Maven libraries, and I can't do this.

I've tried install maven from repository (http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases) but this doesn't work:

> Help > Install new software > ...

[image: Maven Installing ERROR]

It tell me that require more bundles, I've install lot of bundles manually but always require more and I don't know if this is viable.

Has someone complete Maven configuration in *Jaspersoft Studio*? If so, I
would appreciate to know how. I can also use other options while using
Maven to manage the dependencies

Comment: I would like to know that too.

Answer (score 3):

I too faced similar issue.
Since maven (M2Eclipse) needs other dependent tools to function like WTP etc (you can see those in error log details), I figured it would be more time-consuming in finding all those dependencies & install them.

Ultimately, I installed jaspersoft plugin into my eclipse.

From the following link, you can install jaspersoft plugin from into your eclipse by drag-drop of the install button on your eclipse platform.

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jaspersoft-studio

Or you can find it in eclipse marketplace & install it from there.

I installed it on STS. And it installed successfully.

Hope, someone finds this useful.

Comment: Lot of Thanks!! I got a question, you know if this plugin works correctly? Latests versions of jaspersoft works fine and some plugins in eclipse does´t.

Comment: @Mikel I'm currently using the above plugin which has following version:
'Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0'.
This works fine with my STS (Version: 4.0.1.RELEASE). Hopefully this should work for your eclipse version.

Comment: Thans for the info!!

Answer (score 0):

Install the Maven plugin in Jaspersoft Studio v6.20.6

Open "Jaspersoft Studio" > Go to the "Help" Menu > "Install New Software"

1. Select "All Available Sites" (or search specific) -> It will display the result below
2. type filter text as "m2e"
3. Select "Maven Integration for Eclipse" & "Maven integration for WTP"
4. Continue further installation

Refer image

[image]

Download Jaspersoft Studio: https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio/releases